# Crawl stock availability data from website

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to crawl the stock availability of a certain product from the following website.

**[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2756&spec[]=285"},**{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2768&spec[]=285"},{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2811&spec[]=285"},{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2757&spec[]=285"}],"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"9.0","ratingCount":"6","bestRating":"10"}}

I need the schema.org/Instock or schema.org/OutOfStock to eventually get a notification when the product in on stock so I can buy it.
It is for me personal since availability of Mountainbikes is very limited at the moment.
So I want to build a quick program to get a notification when mount MTB size in on stock
If I have a script to get the data for this specific product I can make a ssis with sql server and set an email notification when the "outstock" field is "instock".
I am familiar with SSIS and SQL server. Could somebody help me get the data fetched from the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do json directly in SSIS, but you can also use SQL Server

Insert the Json in a table using ssis, and then parse it for example using Openjson:

Here I insert your example json in a temp table, and query it using tsql:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =
N'
[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2756&spec[]=285"}
,{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2768&spec[]=285"}
,{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2811&spec[]=285"}
,{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2757&spec[]=285"}]
,"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"9.0","ratingCount":"6","bestRating":"10"}}'


CREATE TABLE #tmp (
      id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
    , json NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (json)
VALUES (@json)

SELECT [AdType]
     , [availability]
     , [price]
     , [priceCurrency]
     , [url]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 json
    FROM #tmp
    ORDER BY id DESC
) a
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(a.json)
    WITH
    (
    AdType VARCHAR(100) '$."@type"'
    , availability NVARCHAR(256)
    , price DECIMAL(19, 2)
    , priceCurrency NVARCHAR(3)
    , url NVARCHAR(512)
    )
```

You have python in your tags. If you are using Python to fetch the data you can just parse the json into a python object directly without using SSIS or SQL server however

Comment: Hi Søren, thanks for sharing. Is this script now also dynamic? Because what happens if the third line on the website will change to "Instock". Will the query then return this also? With sql I can add also date + time running query. So output will be 28-1-2021 13:45 : OutOfStock , 28-1-2021 15:00: OutOfStock , 28-1-2021 17:00 : Instock ,

Comment: In fact I need to get this information: //{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","price":"479.00","priceCurrency":"EUR"," //

From the following URL: url":"https://www.mantel.com/cube-aim-pro&spec[]=9470&spec[]=2768&spec[]=285"}